# When to flag questions that show a lack of knowledge?

Tags: discussion

I've just responded to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/664994), and apparently solved the (first) problem the asker encountered. The question itself hints that the asker has very little knowledge on how to use Linux, basic shell commands, directory structure, etc, and may be extremely out of his/her depth. They're following a tutorial and can't even get all the commands right!

I feel like I should flag this for closing, but similarly the question was fairly well structured: clear definition of problem, evidence of some attempts to solve the problem themselves, command output, etc. Not the worst question I've come across, certainly.

Should we flag such 'well-formed' questions as off-topic/not-professional-sysadmin-stuff? Or migrate elsewhere?

Comment: I gave it an upvote at Super User.

Comment: For that matter, you may as well flag every question asked since yesterday morning.  You'll be right about 98% of the time.

Comment: I laughed when I saw the title for this quesiton: "When to flag questions that show a lack of knowledge?". Don't all questions show a lack of knowledge? (I do understand the rest of the relevant question)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are no hard and fast rules.  You should do what feels right to you, a friendly moderator will agree and something may happen or they won't.

That particular question is probably better fit for another SE site, personally I chose Super User.